# Is there a form of C++ references in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

In C++ I have previously used "&" reference variables to refer to a location inside a vector, I used this as an aliasing mechanism while still allowing myself to store data in the array

Does a similar mechanism exist for items stored in an object in Javascript?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/4515720

Comment: JS is a pass-by-value language. But in case of objects, that value is a reference. Maybe you can use that.